# How to extract the week from a date in MySQL using arbitrary weekday as the start of the week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set (say, "x" dated by "xdate") for which I would like to get weekly averages on a week by week basis. I can do this with SQL (for MYSQL) like so:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(xdate), 
    WEEKOFYEAR(xdate), avg(x) 
FROM 
    xtable
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(xdate),
    WEEKOFYEAR(xdate);
```

However, I would also like to group the weeks using an arbitrary weekday as the "start of week." Looking at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_wee) it seems one can make the WEEK call using a parameter to indicate the start of the week as Sunday or Monday. I would like to make a call having the start of the week be any day of the week. So averages could be from Wednesday to Wednesday, and so on. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the function logic by one day if you add one day.

For example:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(xdate),
  WEEKOFYEAR(date_add(xdate, interval 1 day) ),
  avg(x)
FROM
  xtable
GROUP BY
  YEAR(xdate),
  WEEKOFYEAR(date_add(xdate, interval 1 day));
```

This way you can can shift the beginning of the week as many days as you want.